# How to change font name for whole document in word with python docx

Tags: python-2.7, python-docx

I'm trying to change the font for the entire word document to "Times New Roman", here is my code:

```
from docx import Document
from docx.shared import Pt
def set_font_for_entire_document(docx_path):
    doc = Document(docx_path)
    for paragraph in doc.paragraphs:
        for run in paragraph.runs:
            font = run.font
            font.name = 'Times New Roman'
            font.size = Pt(13)
    doc.save(docx_path)
input_docx_path = 'E:\TEST FONT.docx'
set_font_for_entire_document(input_docx_path)
```

It worked, however, it only changed the size of the font, not the font name to "Times New Roman" as I wanted.
Please help me.

I searched the forum posts with many similar keywords but none of them could help me with that.

Answer (score 0):

Try to export your docx file to xml so you can see if you are applying the font to the right place:
with open('yourFileName.xml', 'w') as f:
f.write(doc._element.xml)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).